# Different output image when using coordinate in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am getting different output images when using named v/s raw coordinates in tikz-3dplot.
Is there way to print out what the value of coodinates are to help debug or check any log files.
Minimal example below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{100}%right hand
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \def\xmax{2}
        \def\ymax{2}
        \def\dz{0.2}
        \coordinate (M) at (0.5*\xmax,0.5*\ymax,0);
        \draw[fill=green!40!white, opacity = 0.5,tdplot_main_coords]
        ({0},{0},{0}) to [out=30,in=200]
        ({0},{\ymax},{0}) to
        ({\xmax},{\ymax},{0}) to[out=200,in=30]
        ({\xmax},{0},{0}) to
        ({0},{0},{-\dz}) to
         (M) to
        (0,0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{100}%right hand
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \def\xmax{2}
        \def\ymax{2}
        \def\dz{0.2}
        \draw[fill=green!40!white, opacity = 0.5,tdplot_main_coords]
        ({0},{0},{0}) to [out=30,in=200]
        ({0},{\ymax},{0}) to
        ({\xmax},{\ymax},{0}) to[out=200,in=30]
        ({\xmax},{0},{0}) to
        ({0},{0},{-\dz}) to
         (0.5*\xmax,0.5*\ymax,0) to
        (0,0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not use `tdplot_main_coords` when defining the symbolic coordinate `M`. If you replace

```
\coordinate (M) at (0.5*\xmax,0.5*\ymax,0);
```

by

```
\path[tdplot_main_coords] (0.5*\xmax,0.5*\ymax,0) coordinate (M);
```

both results match.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{100}%right hand
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \def\xmax{2}
        \def\ymax{2}
        \def\dz{0.2}
        \path[tdplot_main_coords] (0.5*\xmax,0.5*\ymax,0) coordinate (M);
        \draw[fill=green!40!white, opacity = 0.5,tdplot_main_coords]
        ({0},{0},{0}) to [out=30,in=200]
        ({0},{\ymax},{0}) to
        ({\xmax},{\ymax},{0}) to[out=200,in=30]
        ({\xmax},{0},{0}) to
        ({0},{0},{-\dz}) to
         (M) to
        (0,0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{100}%right hand
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \def\xmax{2}
        \def\ymax{2}
        \def\dz{0.2}
        \draw[fill=green!40!white, opacity = 0.5,tdplot_main_coords]
        ({0},{0},{0}) to [out=30,in=200]
        ({0},{\ymax},{0}) to
        ({\xmax},{\ymax},{0}) to[out=200,in=30]
        ({\xmax},{0},{0}) to
        ({0},{0},{-\dz}) to
         (0.5*\xmax,0.5*\ymax,0) to
        (0,0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `calc` library, which gets automatically loaded by `tikz-3dplot`, allows you to compare the screen coordinates of named nodes/coordinates. The inofficial library [`3dtools`](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools) allows you to retrieve the coordinates that were used to define the node/coordinate but at this point does not store the information in which coordinate systems they were defined.

Comment: Thanks @Schrodingger's cat. Based on your answer I found that passing 'tdplot_main_coords' to tikzpicture like so :  also ` \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords].. \end{tikzpicture}` also works.

Comment: @Haaput Of course, yes. This is what one usually does, or one uses a `scope`.